# Is it possible to improve relevancy-score for future queries in Solr?

Tags: solr

I'd like each given result to have thumbs-up/down buttons on the client-side, that will affect future queries in-order to improve the relevancy score of those result.
Meaning - if a user searched "Apple" and got a result of an instance related to "Oranges", and the user thinks this result is not relevant his query, he should be able to tell the system that. 
I was wondering what's the best approach to try implementing this feature? Does Solr even support in any way such feature.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing the goal is to keep it related to the queries being made, and not only that the document is less important overall?

Comment: Yes, exactly. it needs to be less/more relevant for that specific query.

Comment: How specific do you want to track this? What about something deemed in-relevant for "apple store", but relevant for "apple"? Are "orange" still relevant for "apple store", even if someone downvoted it for "apple"? (i.e. only exact queries)?

Comment: Ideally, I guess it would be better if it would refine the score for all queries that are related in a way (to a certain degree) to that original query. For instance:
I searched "Apple stores" and got "oranges", and I downvoted that, when I'd look for "Apple Pie" I would probably don't want to get oranges, since "apple store" and "apple pie" are very much related.

Comment: Apple Store (where you buy iphones) isn't really related to apple pie - neither is raspberry pi's :-) It's a (very) hard problem to assign and make sense of differing meaning for computers. A possible (slightly hackish) solution that might yield quick results is to take each word in your query and (one solution for a smaller number of queries for each document) index fields with each term as a dynamic field name, then apply a boost to each document based on the value of that field (i.e. index `relevancy_apple` as a field). Another option is score-based payloads in a single field w/each term.

Comment: I used a bad example, but for the purposes of my engine, what I stated initially is still correct the majority of the use-cases for me :) But what about if I would want to refine scores for the results for the *exact* same query?

Comment: In that case I'd do the same, but include the complete query as the field name - or as the token together with a payload for the boost. You can apply an alphabetic sort for the query terms to at least make sure that `store apple` and `apple store` are assumed to be the same query.

Comment: That was extremely helpful :) Thank you!